# How to dynamically change Plupload url

Tags: php, jquery, plupload

I have setup Plupload to send to a PHP script checking for a parameter "gal" like:

```
$("#uploader").plupload({
  url : 'upload.php?gal='+$('#gallery').val()
});
```

This retrieves the value from a drop down, but it grabs the value of the drop down when initialized.  I need to change this every time the drop down is changed.  I tried:

```
$("#gallery").change(function() {
  $('#uploader').data("uiPlupload").options.url = 'upload.php?gal='+$(this).val();
});
```

This is changes the url for this value, however I guess this isn't the correct parameter as even though I can see in Firebug that this changes, it still uses the initialized value.

I have also tried:

```
$("#uploader").bind('BeforeUpload', function(up, file) {
  up.settings.url = 'upload.php?gal='+$("#gallery").val();
});
```

This doesn't get triggered at all.

Can someone shed some light on how I would change this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out.  You have to get the uploader instance and then set in the settings like:

```
$("#gallery").change(function() {
    var up = $('#uploader').plupload('getUploader');
    up.settings.url = 'upload.php?gal='+$(this).val()
});
```